# Adding to a duration before a certain condition in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have ticker data about sports matches of the type:

```
    playtime    event  game
0    00:10:34    'red card for player 10'  game_id_0123
1    00:00:00    'start of second half' game_id_0123
2    00:10:00    'goal for team blue'    game_id_0123
```

What is the easiest way using pandas (python) to add, say 45 minutes to the `playtime` for each `event` after the start of the second half for every `game`?
I am considering using the `index` and doing a (group by) condition for each game id. But that sounds overly complex, and I fear I am missing a feature in pandas that would allow me to do that more easily or in a standard matter.

Comment: Hi Steve, here the events are always in chronological order?

Comment: Yes they are, and I would like to leverage that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'playtime': {0: '00:10:34',
                     1: '00:00:00',
                     2: '00:10:00',
                     3: '00:40:00',
                     4: '00:00:00',
                     5: '00:05:00'},
        'event': {0: 'red card for player 10',
                  1: 'start of second half',
                  2: 'goal for team blue',
                  3: 'goal for team red',
                  4: 'start of second half',
                  5: 'assist for team red'},
        'game': {0: 'game_id_0123',
                 1: 'game_id_0123',
                 2: 'game_id_0123',
                 3: 'game_id_0124',
                 4: 'game_id_0124',
                 5: 'game_id_0124'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    playtime    event                   game
0   00:10:34    red card for player 10  game_id_0123
1   00:00:00    start of second half    game_id_0123
2   00:10:00    goal for team blue      game_id_0123
3   00:40:00    goal for team red       game_id_0124
4   00:00:00    start of second half    game_id_0124
5   00:05:00    assist for team red     game_id_0124
```

**Code**

make series with 0(first half) and 1(second half)

```
event = 'start of second half'
df['event'].eq(event).groupby(df['game']).cumsum()
```

output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    1
Name: event, dtype: int64
```

make condition(`cond1`) from output, add 45min if 1

```
cond1 = df['event'].eq(event).groupby(df['game']).cumsum().eq(1)
df['playtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['playtime'])
df['playtime'] = df['playtime'].mask(cond1, df['playtime'] + pd.Timedelta('45m')).dt.time
```

`df`

```
    playtime    event                   game
0   00:10:34    red card for player 10  game_id_0123
1   00:45:00    start of second half    game_id_0123
2   00:55:00    goal for team blue      game_id_0123
3   00:40:00    goal for team red       game_id_0124
4   00:45:00    start of second half    game_id_0124
5   00:50:00    assist for team red     game_id_0124
```

Comment: Thanks Panda Kim; like for rpanai, it is close to what I imagined, I will leave it open a little bit to see if there is a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this can be any easier:

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"playtime": [
        "00:10:34",
        "00:00:00",
        "00:10:00",
        "00:10:34",
        "00:00:00",
        "00:10:00",
        "00:12:00"],
     "event": [
         'red card for player 10',
         'start of second half',
         'goal for team blue',
         'red card for player 12',
         'start of second half',
         'goal for team red',
         'yellow card for player 1'],
     "game": [
         "game_id_0123",
         "game_id_0123",
         "game_id_0123",
         "game_id_0124",
         "game_id_0124",
         "game_id_0124",
         "game_id_0124"]})
```

## Mask when you need to add 45 minutes

```py
df["mask"] = np.where(
    df["event"].eq('start of second half'),
    1,
    np.nan)

first_event_per_game = df.groupby("game")\
    .apply(lambda x: x.index[0]).values

df["mask"] = np.where(
    df.index.isin(first_event_per_game),
    0,
    df["mask"])

df["mask"] = df["mask"].ffill()
```

which now looks like

```bash
   playtime                     event          game  mask
0  00:10:34    red card for player 10  game_id_0123   0.0
1  00:00:00      start of second half  game_id_0123   1.0
2  00:10:00        goal for team blue  game_id_0123   1.0
3  00:10:34    red card for player 12  game_id_0124   0.0
4  00:00:00      start of second half  game_id_0124   1.0
5  00:10:00         goal for team red  game_id_0124   1.0
6  00:12:00  yellow card for player 1  game_id_0124   1.0
```

## add 45 minutes in secod half events

```py
df["playtime"] = np.where(
    df["mask"].eq(1),
    (df["playtime"].astype("M8") + 
     pd.Timedelta(minutes=45)).astype(str).str[11:],
    df["playtime"])
```

Which returns

```bash
   playtime                     event          game  mask
0  00:10:34    red card for player 10  game_id_0123   0.0
1  00:45:00      start of second half  game_id_0123   1.0
2  00:55:00        goal for team blue  game_id_0123   1.0
3  00:10:34    red card for player 12  game_id_0124   0.0
4  00:45:00      start of second half  game_id_0124   1.0
5  00:55:00         goal for team red  game_id_0124   1.0
6  00:57:00  yellow card for player 1  game_id_0124   1.0
```

Comment: thanks rpanai this is a little bit how I was thinking of doing it. I will leave it open a little to see if there is a simpler way. But since you and Panda Kim came up with a very similar solution, it is likely the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Carrega os dados do jogo em um DataFrame do pandas
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('games.csv')

# Cria uma coluna com a duração do evento em segundos
df['duration_secs'] = df['duration'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: 
int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1]))

# Cria uma coluna com a duração do evento após o início da segunda metade
df['duration_secs_2h'] = df['duration_secs'].where(df['half'] == 2, 
df['duration_secs'] + 45 * 60)

# Calcula a duração total do evento após o início da segunda metade para cada jogo
df_grouped = df.groupby('game_id')['duration_secs_2h'].sum()
```